# Relativistic Doppler Effect - calculate frequency $f'$ and $f$ in references $S'$ and $S$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

> Considering that $S$ (fixed) and $S'$ are inertial references which coincides when $t=t'=0$ and their coordinates $(ct,x,y,z)$ and $(ct',x',y',z')$ are related by Lorentz's transformations, calculate what are the frequences $f$ and $f'$ of a moving monocromatic light source (velocity $\vec{v}=v\hat z$ ) in  $S$ and $S'$, respectively ( this light is at rest in relation with $S'$). To do this calculation, assume that, from someone's point of view who is in $S'$, a wave crest of this light is sent at the instant $t'_1$ while the next is sent at the instant $t'_2=t'_1+\delta t'$.

What I have tried was replacing the position $z=vt$ in Lorentz's transformation and obtain a relation between $t'$ and $t$ as a function of $\gamma$. But I don't really know how to link this with $t'_2=t'_1+\delta t'$.

If anyone could help me with that!

Comment: [Deriving relativistic Doppler shift in terms of wavelength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356502/deriving-relativistic-doppler-shift-in-terms-of-wavelength/356691#356691)

Answer (score 1):

The way I should solve this is by direct use of the Lorentz transformation:
$$ct = \gamma (ct' + z' v/c), \quad x = x', \quad y = y', \quad z = \gamma (z' + t'v),$$
inversely,
$$ct' = \gamma (ct - z v/c), \quad x' = x, \quad y' = y, \quad z' = \gamma (z - tv),$$

In $S'$ the light wave is described by 
$$\phi = \sin 2\pi f' (t' - z'/c).$$

Substituting $t'$ and $z'$ with the expressions above gives
$$\phi = \sin 2\pi f' (\gamma(t-zv/c^2) - \gamma(z-tv)/c) 
= \sin 2\pi f' \gamma (1+v/c) (t-z/c).$$

We see that the frequency in $S$ is given by $f = f' \gamma (1+v/c) 
= \sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}} f'$.

Comment: Nice simple answer.  Would you consider editing to define phi for S and phi dash for S' together with the usual connotations just to make it even clearer?

Comment: @m4r35n357. I'm not sure how you mean.

Comment: Phi is defined against dashed quantities, S' f' z'.  You ould call that phi dash.  The define an undashed phi with S, f, z.  No big deal, I still like the answer!

Comment: @m4r35n357. But then I need to explain why $\phi' = \phi.$ As of now, I don't use different symbols since the value is assumed to be the same; it's just the functional form that differs between systems.