# Relativistic doppler efect

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, doppler-effect

I got a little confused with the derivation of doppler effect for light as showed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect). The derivation states that when the source of light and the receiver are moving away from one another, the wavelength as observed by the receiver equals to the wavelength as emitted by the source plus the distance the receiver moved whilst the wave moved one wavelength (as emitted by the source) towards it.

> Suppose one wavefront arrives at the receiver.
>   The next wavefront is then at a distance
>   $\lambda_s = c / f_s$ away from the receiver (where
>   $\lambda_s$ is the wavelength, $f_s$ is the frequency of
>   the waves that the source emits, and $c$ is the
>   speed of light).
>
> The wavefront moves with speed $c$, but at the
>   same time the receiver moves away with
>   speed $v$ during a time $t_s = 1/f_s = \lambda_s/c$, so
>   $$\lambda + v t_s=ct_{r,s} \Longleftrightarrow (1 + v/c) \lambda_s = c t_{r,s} \Longleftrightarrow t_{r,s} = (1 + \beta) \frac{1}{f_s}$$

I don't understand why as when the wavefront will complete the distance the receiver moved away from it previously, the receiver will already have moved again so they won't meet.
Could anyone please explain that to me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: if the receiver has mass it cannot attain speed of light, so light will eventually overtake it

Comment: Of course, but it will take a longer distance for it to catch up as it seems to me.

Comment: true, thus the redshift

Comment: Yes, however i dont understand why they are stating the the wavelength as observed by the receiver is such and not longer as I stated above.

Comment: Related : [Deriving relativistic Doppler shift in terms of wavelength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356502/deriving-relativistic-doppler-shift-in-terms-of-wavelength/356691#356691).